# ArrayList is null when there's only one item

Tags: c#, arraylist, foreach

I have a block of code that works but is, I think, a little inelegant. `advertiserList` is `null` when there's only one item.  Can't C# treat it as a loop with one item?  How can I clean up this code?  Thank.

The inner parts of the `if{}` `else{}` both do the same things.  I'm just interested in getting advertiser info.

```
// build the advertiser loop
var advertiserList = campaignAdvertiserContainer["Advertiser"] as ArrayList;
if (advertiserList != null) // if multiple advertisers exist per campaign
{
    foreach (Dictionary<string, object> advertiser in advertiserList)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> multipleCampaignAdvertiserLookup = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        multipleCampaignAdvertiserLookup.Add("CampaignId", campaign["id"].ToString());
        multipleCampaignAdvertiserLookup.Add("AdvertiserId", advertiser["id"].ToString());
        multipleCampaignAdvertiserLookup.Add("MediaCode", advertiser["MediaCode"].ToString());
        multipleCampaignAdvertiserLookup.Add("BusinessKey", advertiser["BusinessKey"].ToString());
        multipleCampaignAdvertiserLookup.Add("CreatedBy", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName.ToString());
        multipleCampaignAdvertiserLookup.Add("CreatedDt", DateTime.Now.ToString());

        campaignAdvertiserLookupArray.Add(multipleCampaignAdvertiserLookup);
    }
}
// there's only one advertiser, no need to loop
else
{
    Dictionary<string, object> singleAdvertiser = (Dictionary<string, object>)campaignAdvertiserContainer["Advertiser"];
    Dictionary<string, object> singleCampaignAdvertiserLookup = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    singleCampaignAdvertiserLookup.Add("CampaignId", campaign["id"].ToString());
    singleCampaignAdvertiserLookup.Add("AdvertiserId", singleAdvertiser["id"].ToString());
    singleCampaignAdvertiserLookup.Add("MediaCode", singleAdvertiser["MediaCode"].ToString());
    singleCampaignAdvertiserLookup.Add("BusinessKey", singleAdvertiser["BusinessKey"].ToString());
    singleCampaignAdvertiserLookup.Add("CreatedBy", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName.ToString());
    singleCampaignAdvertiserLookup.Add("CreatedDt", DateTime.Now.ToString());

    campaignAdvertiserLookupArray.Add(singleCampaignAdvertiserLookup);
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Something fishy here. At the beginning you ask to treat your campaignAdvertiserContainer["Advertiser"] as an ArrayList and if the result is null then, your else condition cast it to a (Dictionary<string, object>). What is the real content of that variable campaignAdvertiserContainer["Advertiser"] ?

Comment: @Steve They're all `Dictionary<string, object>`.  I found ArrayList to be the only type taht would let me use the `foreach` loop.

Comment: Still missing something. What is the type of campaignAdvertiserContainer ? Could you show the code where you initialize it and add values?

Comment: Try making campaignAdvertiserContainer["Advertiser"] a List<Dicttionary<string,object>>

Comment: @Steve

Dictionary<string, object> 
campaignAdvertiserContainer = (Dictionary<string, object>)campaign["Advertisers"];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this has nothing to do with how C# treats things. It's the code.

`campaignAdvertiserContainer["Advertiser"]` is apparently a single item. The code that put that there should *put* an ArrayList of the single item into there.

Second, `ArrayList` is obsolete. Instead, the code should use `List<Dictionary<string,object>>`.

Answer (score 3):

If you had a collection with one item in it, then yes, you could just use a `foreach` loop no matter what, but that's not what you have.  You have the actual item stuck into that container rather than a collection of size one.

You should modify whatever code puts a value into this object so that it *always* puts in a collection.  If there are no items it should put in an empty collection, if there is one item it should put in a collection with one item, if there is more than one item it should put in all of those items.  If you do that you can always just `foreach` over the result, without needing so much as a `null` check.  Doing this is to write programs that are validated at compile time due to the C# type system.  Not only are they easier to write, but you know that so long as it compiles, it'll work.

You should also avoid using `ArrayList`, instead you should use the generic `List<T>`.  Much like avoiding using an `object` variable to hold onto either an item or a list of items, you should always strive to have statically constrain your types to what you need them to be.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the code that is calling your method: it passes a single item differently from passing multiple items.

The preferred solution would be to change that, and pass an array list with a single item rather than passing a "naked" item when there's only one. If it is not an option, change your code to make an array list yourself, like this:

```
var advertiserList = campaignAdvertiserContainer["Advertiser"] as ArrayList;
if (advertiserList == null) {
    advertiserList = new ArrayList {
         campaignAdvertiserContainer["Advertiser"]
    };
}
```

At this point, advertiserList is what the positive branch of your `if` statement expects. You can replace both branches of the `if` with its first branch (i.e. the one containing the `for` loop).